# Change cell color based on data from another workbook

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two spreadsheets, A and B, residing in different workbooks. I may not make changes to Spreadsheet A. Both contain a list of products. Spreadsheet A has dates corresponding to product as "start" and "stop" columns delimiting a range of dates. Spreadsheet B has the same data but with columns representing individual days:

Spreadsheet A looks like this:

Product Name | Product Code | Start date | Stop Date

Spreadsheet B:

Product Name | Product Code| 1.01|1.02|1.03 etc.

In Spreadsheet B by row I want cells automatically filled black for every day (column) in the timeframe specified in Spreadsheet A. Spreadsheet A is used by entire company and I can't make changes to it. Basically how do I change the data format between spreadsheets from "Start in one cell, Stop in another" to "From Cell 1 to Cell x"?
EDIT: I created a Spreadsheet C in Workbook B that copies both dates and calculates amount of cells that need to be blacked out.

Comment: Using import function but it yields me nothing. All i get is the two columns together

Answer (score 1):

If your Product Names and Product Codes are not unique pairs then I'd suggest starting by concatenating these (eg ColumnC in both spreadsheets) - may well not be necessary. Then, to be able to apply conditional formatting, name ColumnsC:E in `SheetA` as a range (say `RangeCDE`). Finally a formula that returns `TRUE` where required can be applied in conditional formatting in `D2` (say `=AND(VLOOKUP($C2,RangeCDE,2,FALSE)<=D$1,VLOOKUP($C2,RangeCDE,3,FALSE)>=D$1)`):

[image: SO16786576 first example]

There is no need to apply the formula *in the cells*, though that is as shown in the example. (May help if to adjust the formula to exclude either of the limits presently inclusive.)

The `Applies to` range would need to be `=$D$2:{and as far as required}`.

For test data I used:

[image: SO16786576 second example]

Note that all the dates are 'real' dates though formatted differently in `SheetB`.

Comment: They are unique pairs. I could copy paste them from one sheet into another with no difference.Problem is Spreadsheet A is a file used by entire company while Spreadsheet B is for my department only. I can't make changes to Spreadsheet A

Comment: They are in different books. It was supposed to be "So basically i need to change the data format from "Start in one cell, Stop in another" to "From Cell 1 to Cell x" From one workbook to another

Comment: I realized recently that what I tried to accomplish is actually  Gannt chart. But I need to do it in cells and not using the chart function